# How can I create a self-incrementing column for a DataGridView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagridview, webforms

I need to add a self-incrementing column to a DataGridView. Every time a row is added to the grid I want to increment the `No` column.

My `Form_Load` code:

```
Private Sub SAP_OrdenVenta_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 6

    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = ("No")
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = ("NoArticulo")
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = ("Descripcion")
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).Name = ("Cantidad")
    DataGridView1.Columns(4).Name = ("Precio")
    DataGridView1.Columns(5).Name = ("Total")
End Sub
```

The DataGridView Button Click event for the add button:

```
Private Sub btnAgregar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAgregar.Click

    Dim articulo, cantidad As Integer
    Dim precio, total1 As Double
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    articulo = txtArticulo.Text.Trim()
    cantidad = txtCantidad.Text.Trim()
    precio = txtPrecio.Text.Trim()
    total1 = txtPrecio.Text.Trim()

    'Agrego Linea a DataGridView
    Dim row As String() = New String() {1, articulo, "No disponible", cantidad, precio, total1}
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)

End Sub
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: SO is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site, and either translate your question (including title!) into English, or else post it on the [Spanish Stackoverflow site](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Are you sure this is related to asp.net? That `DataGridView1` is quite *suspicious*.

Comment: If this is actually a DataGridView (WinForms), use the CellFormatting event to set `e.Value = e.RowIndex + 1` when `e.ColumnIndex` (or the Column name) matches the *Counter* Column. You could also handle the `RowPostPaint` event and paint a progressive number in the `RowHeader`. If you're using a DataTable as `DataSource` (your adding a row directly to the grid so, no... but you may want to :), you can add an `AutoIncrement` column, with `AutoIncrementStep = 1`

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub btnAgregar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAgregar.Click    
    Dim LastIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim LastNo As Integer = Integer.Parse(DataGridView1.Rows(LastIndex).Cells(0).Value)
    Dim NewNo As String = (LastNo + 1).ToString()

    Dim row As String() = New String() {NewNo, txtArticulo.Text, "No disponible", txtCantidad.Text, txtPrecio.Text, txtPrecio.Text}
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
End Sub
```

Take note, however: if this view is loaded from a real database table, you almost always want to rely on your database's ability to generate ID values. Otherwise, this is a huge race condition waiting to blow up.